# Сортировка в SQL с наличием UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Есть SQL запрос:

```
SELECT question_text, q.publish_time AS qTime, a.time AS aTime, answer_text, u.username AS 'from', i.username AS 'to' FROM tb_questions q 
JOIN tb_question_recipients qr on q.id=qr.id_question 
JOIN tb_users u on q.user_id=u.user_id 
JOIN tb_answers a on q.id=a.question_id 
JOIN tb_users i on i.user_id=a.user_id 
WHERE a.user_id=1
AND q.private=0
UNION 
SELECT question_text, q.publish_time AS qTime, a.time AS aTime, answer_text, u.username AS 'from', i.username AS 'to' FROM tb_questions q 
JOIN tb_question_recipients qr on q.id=qr.id_question 
JOIN tb_users u on q.user_id=u.user_id 
JOIN tb_answers a on q.id=a.question_id 
JOIN tb_users i on i.user_id=a.user_id
WHERE q.user_id=1
AND q.private=0
```

Хочу также применить сортировку по `aTime` но не знаю где и куда всатвлять `ORDER BY atime`. Пытался вставить в конце запроса, но не получилось

Comment: Подзапросы надо обрамить скобками, а потом уже `ORDER BY`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: Все должно работать и без скобок. Какая ошибка при вставке в конце запроса сортировки?

Comment: @JavaJunior #1250 - Table 'a' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list

Comment: @JavaJunior Все заработало

Comment: @JavaJunior Вы были правы, без скобок тоже работает. Уменя просто была ошибка при выборке (я указал неправильное название столбца)